# Google Play in-app billing giving an item for free

Tags: android, mobile, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I already have a completely free app published at Google Play store.

Since the app is more popular than I have thought, I decided to lock some of the features and demand in-app billing before using it. However, I prefer that all existing users will continue to enjoy have the premium features for free.

So, I thought about the following:

- Upload a version with in-app billing for free, so that the existing users
  will "purchase" it for free.
- After certain amount of time start charging for the items, but since
  he existing users already own the premium items they wouldn't be
  hurt.

Is there a way to grant some users an item for "free"?  In the In-App billing documentation is  written that there must be a price for all in-app billing items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it from google. You will be having 2 test-cases:-

1. Existing user
2. New user
   You have to store unique `user-id` on your server and when you implement your in-App in application send this user-id to your server.

Case 1:- 
Your server will match it with existing DB if it matches the id return you success message.

Case 2:-
For new users along with this user-id your app should send purchase token to your server for verification and after verifying the purchase your server should send success message.

Common task:-
When your application starts you should always call restoreTransaction() after that you will get a list from google contains information about already purchased items and you will unlock that content.
Make sure you have server verification implementation in you app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about keeping a unique user-id. It is a great idea! However, is not that useful for me, since the app is client only and I don't have time to implement a server side right now.  I accept your answer since this a is how it should be done. The solution for me, would be just not charge the users who upgrade, but next time, when they install an app on another device, they will be charged.

Comment: how you are going to check whether user has upgrade the app or fresh install because when user upgrade any app full apk file is downloaded from google play and re-install the app on device in same way as new app install?

Comment: I am aware of what you have written about. Don't you think that it might be a fair compromise to start charging customers for each full new installation?

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you but I want to know how you will distinguish between both new install and update?

Comment: @Ankit if you use any SharedPreferences in your app then you can check that for values. If it's a fresh install than the values will be non existant if it's an update the values will be there.
But beware if user uninstall/clears data of the app then the app will think it's a fresh install...

I recommend to start charging even the existing users

Comment: But those SharedPreferences can be deleted if user did clear data in settings>>Application>>your app

Comment: @Ankit, I can know whether a user updated or not by checking some data in the sqlite database that the app stored.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could partially accomplish what you desire, without the use of a server:

1. Update your app with a new version that will write a unique value to SharedPreferences.  This value should be a hash of an ID that is unique to the device (or at least, that not many other devices would share).  The reason that the value should be relatively unique is to prevent it from being shared among later users.  If you want it to survive a re-install, you might also write it to an area of the user's external memory that will not be removed when your app is installed.
2. Wait a sufficiently long time so that most of your present users will have updated to the new version.  In the process, any new users during this phase will also get the unique value in their SharedPreferences.
3. Release a new version that does *not* write the unique ID, and which enables the features for which you would like to charge *only* if *either* the ID is present, or if the user has paid via in-app billing.

This is not perfect, but it could allow at least *most* of your present users to continue to access the features.

I don't know whether this would violate your agreement with Google Play, and you would need to check into that issue yourself.  The fact that you presented the app to your present users as being free and now wish to charge for some of its features might be seen as a misrepresentation unless you grandfather in your existing users, and the approach I've just outlined does not guarantee that all existing users will be successfully granted access.

Note that the approach submitted in another answer that would require using your own server would seem to have these same problems, because you would need to release a new version of your app that had code to communicate with your server, and there's no way to force your current users to update to the new version within a specific interval of time.  Otherwise, how will you collect the unique IDs that identify your present users on your server's database, since users of free apps are not generally known to the developer?

A cleaner approach would be to add *new* features that integrate tightly with existing features, making them more valuable, and also making any *content* already entered using the *old* features more valuable.  You could continue to provide existing features free, but charge for the new features.

By taking this approach, no current users would be deprived of functionality, and you could also charge your current users (and not just new users) for the value-added features.  Using this approach could be not only more agreeable to your users, but also potentially more remunerative for you, since you'll have your entire current user base as potential paying customers.

Also, you might consider that your app's present popularity may well be due to the features for which you now would like to charge.  And so, you may fail to attract a continuing stream of new users once those features are no longer free.

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer.  I am planning to do something similar to what you have proposed.  1) I will keep track of existing users (as much as I can) using SharedPreferences.  I even don't need to release an intermediate version since I can know whether a user updated or not by checking some data in the sqlite database that app stored. 2) I will add cool stuff to features I am going to charge.

Comment: Just remember that SharedPreferences will go away on an uninstall, and  also, if the user has multiple devices, the value may not automatically be available on those devices if installed there later.

Charging for completely new functionality still seems like the cleanest approach to me, but you know your app, and your users, much better so it may be that in your case distinguishing between current and future users is a good approach.  I'm afraid that continuing to distinguish between your two classes of users could turn into a real headache going forward.

Comment: Also, if you are using an existing value written to a local database to distinguish between grandfathered and new users, there is the possibility that such a value could be faked, unless you already have a validation process in place for it (such as I described in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

While not feasible for apps with significant numbers of downloads, as of January 2016, you can grant up to 500 promo codes per app per quarter.

Answer (score 2):

I  see this is a really old thread, and the accepted answer is outdated. There's now an official solution.

Google introduced [`Promotional Codes`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime#Implement-promo) couple of years before and that is exactly what you're looking for.
You can create Promo Codes on the Play Console under `Your App -> User Acquisition -> Promotion`.

> You can use promotions to give users a paid app or in-app product for free with a promo code. You can create promotions to reward loyal fans, acquire new users, and reconnect with previous users. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495).